# MVC passing data to partial view with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have view with button, and when the button is clicked partial view is loaded.(see code below), in some reason my .load function passes the object but Name is null and Id is 0

My View controller method:

```
public TestModel DoSomething()
    {
        TestModel m = new TestModel();
        m.Name = "dosomething";
        m.Id = 3;

        return m;
    }
```

My partial view Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult _Products(TestModel m)
    {           
        return PartialView("_Products", m);
    }
```

my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".example").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "DoSomething/",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#partialViewPlace").load("/Test/_Products", data);
        }
    });

});
});
```

When I debug the data parameter is passed but name is null and id is 0

Comment: You're not passing `data` to `load()` - that's the callback handler. Also making two AJAX requests seems redundant. Just make one and return the HTML you need from that. Also, remove `async: false`. It's horrendous practice. If you check the console you'll even see the browser giving you a warning telling you not to use it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan http://api.jquery.com/load/ `.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )` - looks like it's the correct usage (although not one I'd use myself)

Comment: From further down that page *"The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed"* - so try changing your action to `public ActionResult _Products([FromBody] TestModel m)`

Comment: @Grizabela try changing return type of DoSomething method to ActionResult and returning a Json(m)

Comment: Thank you, but nothing worked. I want to pass data to partial view from different controller, this is why I am doing this. If you can give me idea how to do it in different way?

Comment: To get a partial view from a different controller, you can instantiate the other controller and call it as any other object/class/method.

Comment: there are a couple things in your example that you might need to change.  change your return type to partial view result and set the html element instead.  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006859/mvc-shared-partial-views-using-different-controllers-and-models/19007486#19007486 for how I do it

Comment: @Matt Bodily It's good example, but what if you have to pass parameters to the partial View. In your example you create the model for the partial view in the partial view action.

Comment: the data parameter in the ajax call is where you would put those parameters.  just change your controller to take them as an input and build your model accordingly